# Select multiple images from gallery and then upload them to Firebase Storgae - but get an ENOENT (No such file or directory) error

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

everyone. I would like to select several images in order to upload them to Firebase Storage in the next step. However, when I try to do this, I get the following error message:

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/media/external/images/media/1000003658: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)**

This is how I request the permissions:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
```

My complete permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And here's the part where I store each image path in an array that I then want to iterate through to upload each image:

```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PIC && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if(data?.clipData != null)
        {

        val anzahl = data!!.clipData?.itemCount

            if(data!!.clipData?.itemCount!! <= 6 && listImg.size+1 <= 6 ) {


                for (i in 0 until anzahl!!) {

                    var path = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
                    listImg.add(path)
                }

                myAdapterForImg.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Du kannst nur 6 Bilder auswählen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }


        }
        else if(data?.data != null)
        {
            val url = data?.data!!.path
            listImg.add(Uri.parse(url))

            Log.d("PATH",Uri.parse(url).toString())
            myAdapterForImg.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
 }
```

And here in this for loop I get the error in addOnFailureListener():

```
        for (i in 0 until listImg.size) {

        var file = Uri.fromFile(File(listImg[i].toString()))
        val riversRef = storageRef.child("images/${file.lastPathSegment}")
        var uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file)
        
        try {
            uploadTask.addOnProgressListener { taskSnapshot  ->
                val progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred) / taskSnapshot.totalByteCount
                Log.d("TAG", "Upload is $progress% done")
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded.. " + progress.toInt() + "%")

            }.addOnPausedListener {
                Log.d("TAG", "Upload is paused")
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e("ERROR:",it.toString())
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            }.addOnSuccessListener {
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                val uri = riversRef.downloadUrl

                Log.d("DownloadURL:" ,uri.toString())
            }
        }catch(e: Exception)
        {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
```

my Intent for image pick:

```
        var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_PIC);
```

Comment: You did not post code that would/could produce such a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: And you do not need that READ and WRITE permission to select and upload images.

Comment: Added the missing code

Comment: `var file = Uri.fromFile(File(listImg[i].toString()))` This is impossible code. You cannot use the File class for an uri in that list as the uri is a content scheme.

Comment: [Use `putStream()` rather than `putFile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_stream). Use a ` ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're accessing an image from the external folder. Select the images from your images section and it will work. This is because of Scoped Storage.

If you have to use external images write a program to copy your images from your external storage to your app-specific directory and then take the URL from there.

something like this

```
  public static File copyFileToInternal(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(fileUri, new String[]{OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE}, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            long size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE));

            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + displayName);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
                byte buffers[] = new byte[Constants.CHAT_FILE_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                int read;
                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                return file;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```